# Loading resource files and retrieving bitmaps

Tags: delphi

I wanted to put plenty of small bitmaps into one *.res file. But I do not want to link it with compiler, but let it rest on the hard drive. Potentially I would create more of them.

Is there a way how to take this resource file, read it and load the bitmap with exact name? something like:

```
Bitmap.LoadFromResourceFile(AFileName: TFileName; const BMPName: string);
```

`Bitmap.LoadFromResourceFile(GetCurrentDir + '\sprites.res', 'SMILE')`

All the stuff around *.res files is concerning the compiled ones, but I have not found any solution, which I described above.

thanx

Comment: I don't quite see the point, you can create resource only dlls without much effort. Anyway, you can do it reading/parsing the file - resource editors do it. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648007%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is the spec.

Comment: @Sertac Akzuz: I have not thought of creating dlls. I wanted to create them with editor and then save them for the latter use in app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, a resource is compiled into an executable, whether that be in the main application or an external DLL, but it is still compiled nonetheless.  There is no way to save bitmaps from an editor into a .res file without compiling it, as it is a compiled file.  If you don't want the bitmaps compiled into the application, you can either save individual .bmp files and then load them via `TBitmap.LoadFromFile()`, or else compile them into a resource DLL and load them using `LoadLibrary()` and `TBitmap.LoadFromResource...()`.

Comment: @Remy: "There is no way to save bitmaps from an editor into a .res file without compiling it, as it is a compiled file"... and what about *.res files which are regularly saved via Image editor in Delphi? I thought it is a special format like animated gif... that's why I thought It would be reasonable to simply make bitmaps in Image Editor in delphi save them into res file, and .... so on.... 
Image Editor in Delphi CAN open them, edit them, and save them. So I feel a little bit confused now....

Comment: Image editor compiles the images into the .res file. If you want to put images in files, store them as image files. There's nothing to be gained from putting them in .res containers unless you link those resources to a PE module.

Comment: A .res file is designed to be used by a compiler to put the data into an executable. It is an intermediate file type, like an .obj or .dcu file. Don't be confused by the fact that Image Editor and most other *resource* editors know how to edit .res files directly. That is merely a convenience as an alternative to using separate .bmp and .rc files. The fact remains that there is no API for accessing .res file data, you would have to write that logic manually. But there is an API for accessing resource data once it has been compiled into an executable.

Comment: @Remy@David  OK... It seems to be a dead end... Thanks for explanation